# What's the right adjective or noun for someone who does not trust the intelligence of another person?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

Is there an adjective or a noun about being unable to trust the intelligence of another person? A doubter who refuse to believe that someone is intellectually competent?

For example, Alice refuses to believe that Bob can solve the problem. She is ________. She is a _________.

Comment: Welcome! For word requests, please edit the question to give a sample sentence showing how the word would be used.

Comment: Also, please clarify whether multiple words or idioms are okay. There's an idiom of "a doubting Thomas," but more for a skeptic than someone who suspects incompetence.

Comment: There are professionals to whom this might apply. And power of attorney may be involved in some cases.

Comment: I doubt (heh) that there's a word that combines both skepticism and an assumption that the other person is unintelligent, but you may be able to combine some words. Such a stance could be *patronizing* or *belittling*. If a bias is involved, it could often simply be referenced (e.g. "sexist skepticism" or "mansplaining").

Comment: If there is some apprehension or outright fear, *She is wary of him* may be appropriate. I'm not sure there is a word that means skeptical specifically of someone else's intelligence.

Comment: Not sure there's a better expression than obvious ones like "she thinks he's stupid" or "she doesn't trust him (to get it right)" or "she has no faith in him".

Comment: *Doubt* is not the same thing as *disbelief*.  The question here is ambiguous, because doubt and uncertainty are often used in polite discourse to soften the pain of outright rejection. It’s not clear whether the OP is asking for a euphemism or a hard-and-precise term. Maybe one could say that Alice has *considered the odds*. She is a *realist*.

Comment: Turns out OP wanted rejection.  *dubious* would have been a good term for skepticism.

Comment: *She is ________. She is a _________.* neither of these are sufficient context. More contextual clarification is required.

Comment: Funny how nobody ever shows up here asking for our help in saying something ***nice*** about somebody else. Instead it's always about saying horrible things about something we disapprove of, even though this has never required fancy words to sting the worst.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

She is a **snob**.

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/snob):

> 2. a person who believes himself or herself an expert or connoisseur in a given field and is condescending toward or disdainful of those
>    who hold other opinions or have different tastes regarding this field

And you might want to add "dismissive."

Comment: No. Here, Alice may believe that she can't solve the problem either. Or she may be on a viva panel, about to reject a candidate.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - I hadn't thought about that.  How about *pessimist*?

Comment: OP hasn't clarified as yet.